# Firestore function GET by chosen category

Tags: node.js, firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore

I need help with `GET` function on Firebase.

This code is intended to fetch data from firestorage:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
 const snapshot = await admin
   .firestore()
   .collection("articles")
   .orderBy("createdate", "desc")
   .get();
 const articles = [];
 snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   const data = doc.data();
   articles.push({ id: doc.id, ...data });
 });
 res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(articles));
});
```

but how can I render that data by the tags if I call it

```
app.get("/:tag", async (req, res) => {
```

My data looks like this

```
collection - articles
                    - id 
                         - title
                         - body
                         - tags - [0]culture
                                - [1]technology
```

Comment: Do you want to get docs list where tags are similar ?

Comment: @Ashish yes someting like category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the solution with this code

```
app.get("/tag/:tag", async (req, res) => {
  await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("articles")
    .where("tags", "array-contains", req.params.tag)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const articles = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        articles.push({ id: doc.id, ...data });
      });
      return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(articles));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(404);
    });
});
```

i use  `.where("tags", "array-contains", req.params.tag)`